# Complementary Error Function Integral

Tags: integration

I'm trying to evaluate this integral: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{Erfc}^2(x) e^{ax+b}dx$$

Initially I am working with $a=1$ and $b=0.$ I've tried integrating by parts in a couple of different ways, but haven't found a solution yet. What other methods could be used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\mathrm{Erfc}(x) = 2[1-\Phi(x\sqrt2)] = 2\Phi(-x\sqrt2)$$
where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution (and later on $\phi(\cdot)$ will denote the standard normal density).

So

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{Erfc}^2(x) e^{ax+b}dx = 4e^b\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{ax}\Phi(-x\sqrt2)^2 dx$$
Integrate by parts
$$I = 4e^b\frac 1a\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{de^{ax}}{dx}\Phi(-x\sqrt2)^2 dx$$

$$=4e^b\frac 1a e^{ax}\Phi(-x\sqrt2)^2 \Big|_{-\infty}^{\infty} + \sqrt2\frac {4e^b}a\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{ax}2\Phi(-x\sqrt2)\phi(-x\sqrt2) dx $$

The first term equals zero. Define $z =x\sqrt2 \Rightarrow dz = \sqrt2 dx$. Make the change of variables, and use the symmetry property of $\phi(\cdot)$ to obtain

$$I = \frac {4e^b}a\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{(a/\sqrt2)z}2\phi(z)\Phi(-z) dz$$

Now, $2\phi(z)\Phi(-z)$ is the density function of a [skew-normal random variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution), (with location parameter $0$, scale parameter $1$, and "skew"(shape) parameter $-1$), so the integral is the moment generating function of this distribution in $t= a/\sqrt2$, which for our particular case becomes
$$MGF_{SN}(t) = 2e^{t^2/2}\Phi(-t/\sqrt2)=2e^{a^2/4}\Phi(-a/2)$$

Collecting terms

$$I =2^3\cdot a^{-1}\cdot  e^{b+a^2/4}\cdot \Phi(-a/2)$$

Comment: Thank you so much, especially for the clear exposition and step-by-step evaluation!

Comment: My pleasure. Whenever you see an error function in the integrand, always try to transform it into a standard normal - especially after the explosion of research around the skew normal family of distributions, there is a good chance that a solution will eventually be found in this way.